# ElementTree - Finding parent of a child that is only listed as parent in a tree

Tags: python, elementtree

I've got a problem with python's etree.

I have a xml document that follows the following logic: The document is a chapter, which has sections. Sections can have sections as well. Otherwise sections have titles and paragraphs. So, basically like this:

```
<chapter>
  <section>#problem
    <title>Title A</title>
    <paragraph />
    <section>
      <title>Title B</title>
      <paragraph />
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>Title C</title>
      <paragraph />
    </section>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

Now I am using Pythons ElementTree to get the position of the different elements to their parent, using the basic code of:

```
def get_node_parent_info(root, node):
    parent_map = {c:p for p in root.iter() for c in p}
    parent = parent_map[node]
    return parent, list(parent).index(node)

def delete_from_tree(file, title):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=subfile)
    root = tree.getroot()            
    for element in root.iter():
        if "title" in element.tag and element.text in title_list:
            parent, index = get_node_parent_info(root, node)
            grandparent, grand_index = get_node_parent_info(root, parent)
            grandparent.remove(parent)


file_path = "C:/xml_archive/document.xml"

delete_from_tree(file_path, "Title C") #works fine
delete_from_tree(file_path, "Title A") #KeyError
```

Now I run into the following problem:
Whenever I want to get the marked section in its relation to the chapter, I'll get a KeyError, because the section is not in that list as a child, only as a parent. (I've had the code print the dictionary and there that section only appears as a child, while the chapter does not appear at all.)

I already tried a guess, by writing an exception that in the case a node is not in the list as a key/child, it should name "root" as parent. But apparently that is not right either.

So, what do I do? Can anybody help?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Then copy-paste that complete program into your question. For more information about why such a program is useful, see [mcve] in the [ask] section of the [help].

Comment: What line is throwing your `KeyError`?

Comment: @gr1zzly be4r `parent = parent_map[node]` after the function is called with `grandparent, grand_index = get_node_parent_info(root, parent)`

Comment: You have several undefined names in your code, including `ET`, `subfile`, and `title_list`. Please post a short, runnable program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, your example works perfectly for me: http://ideone.com/wAc5vS